# Expand use block in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

How to expand "use block" at the top of class in PhpStorm 2017.1 by default to see all imported namespaces? Is there any setting?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set these kind of settings in the `code folding` area. In this case these are `Imports` so check those off in the settings.

Go to:
Settings > Editor > General > Code folding

See image. 
 
[image: Code folding]

Answer (score 5):

It's controlled by Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding | Imports.